# Mocking Django for plugin: can't find settings.py

Tags: django

I'm trying to write test for a django plugin called Dynamic Response (available on GitHub), but I'm having some issues. Using mock I'm trying to mock certain Django methods like render_to_response, (i'm not going to test django after all) but when I try to do so, i get an error message saying it can't find settings.py, which it shouldn't as this is a plugin to be used in other projects, not a project in itself. I've tried the following code:

```
class ResponseTest (unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('dynamicresponse.response.render_to_response')
    def test_is_testframework_working(self, render_to_response):
        from dynamicresponse.response import SerializeOrRender
        SerializeOrRender()
```

Which, as stated, gives an error message. Stubbing HttpResponse, HttpRedirect does not throw these errors...

gives the following stacktrace

```
Response (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: response (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: response
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 252, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 230, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/skinney/Workspace/django-dynamicresponse/tests/response.py", line 5, in <module>
    class ResponseTest (unittest.TestCase):
  File "/Users/skinney/Workspace/django-dynamicresponse/tests/response.py", line 7, in ResponseTest
    @patch('dynamicresponse.response.render_to_response')
  File "/Users/skinney/Workspace/django-dynamicresponse/tests/mock.py", line 720, in patch
    target = _importer(target)
  File "/Users/skinney/Workspace/django-dynamicresponse/tests/mock.py", line 514, in _importer
    thing = _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path)
  File "/Users/skinney/Workspace/django-dynamicresponse/tests/mock.py", line 503, in _dot_lookup
    __import__(import_path)
  File "/Users/skinney/Workspace/django-dynamicresponse/dynamicresponse/response.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.models.manager import Manager
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Can you post the error message/traceback?

Comment: I ended up writing the unit-tests as part of the example project of Dynamic Response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't test django apps without any project (real or dummy, whatever) having its own settings file.